# playing video with Qt’s QtWebKit module

Tags: qt, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4, pyside

if you're using Google Chrome ，When you open the following link
https://d2pq0u4uni88oo.cloudfront.net/projects/79786/video-87361-h264_high.mp4
you'll see a video player ,then if you "inspect element" and you will See the html5 video tag there

I wonder if we could accomplish the same functionality with Qt’s QtWebKit module
can anyone give a code sample with the above link ?

Comment: I think you have to recompile QtWebKit enabling video support, because it's disabled by default, at least at Qt4. And probably it is disabled, because it's not quite working...

Answer (score 1):

Try enabling plugins for QtWebKit, then it should work (just tried it):

```
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebSettings
QWebSettings.globalSettings().setAttribute(QWebSettings.PluginsEnabled, True)
```

Comment: Thank you. It should be noted that this works for sites that use plugins to display videos like YouTube. But if you want to embed your own HTML5 videos it won't work.

Comment: @Speakeasys This is a link to a plain mp4 video, just tried it again (with both Qt4 and Qt5), and it opens a player without any problem, even without enabling any plugins, and it also works within a html5 video tag. It didn't before if I recall correctly back then when this question was asked, so maybe a change in Qt/WebKit since then. If it doesn't there may be some qt multimedia related libraries not installed.